# Generic function and new constraint

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics, interface

How can I use two parameters while one inherits from **IProject** and other has a **new()** constraint? The following doesn't pass compilation with the **"Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint" error.**

```
public static T CreateNewProject<T, V>(string token, string projectName) where V : IProject<T>, T new()
{
    T project = new T(); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to apply constraints to multiple parameters, then you need to add second `where` as:

```
where V : IProject<T> 
where T : new()
```

And also, you need to return something from your method:

```
public static T CreateNewProject<T, V>(string token, string projectName) 
    where V : IProject<T> 
    where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

P.S: For applying `new` constraint, the type argument must have a ***public parameterless constructor.***

Read [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for more information.